# Ace redactor не работает на Zend framework

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, zend-framework

Суть проблемы есть проект на zend framework 1, в нем нужно подключить ace редактор. 
Когда пытаюсь его подключить выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < theme-twilight.js:1 
> UncaughtSyntaxError: Unexpected token < ace.js:1 
> Uncaught Error: couldn't load module ace/theme/twilight or it didn't
call define(…)
```

Вызываю я его таким вот образом (как в демо на гитхабе)

```
<pre id="editor">function foo(items) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i &lt; items.length; i++) {
        alert("Ace Rocks " + items[i]);
    }
}</pre>

<script src="/scripts/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
</script>
```

Штука в том что если это просто обычная страничка то все работает отлично, когда пытаюсь его вызвать конкретно на этом проекте, происходит такая штука.

Answer (score 1):

Он не хотел работать по такому пути src="/scripts/src-noconflict/ace.js", хотя остальные скрипты работают по нему прекрасно, поменял путь на такой src="/public/scripts/src-noconflict/ace.js" и все прекрасно заработало, очень странное поведение